# Java Eclipse Error

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

When I run my program I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: run/Run
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: run.Run
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

My project has never changed and this error has just started to arise.  I've tried cleaning my workplace, deleting it, deleting the settings.  Nothing is working, and nothing has changed in my workplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Run Configuration editor, then check which class is going to be run, and edit it to put the right package name in.

I shouldn't admit it, but sometimes, the best solution in these cases is to create a new project and copy the packages by drag and drop.

Comment: Creating a new project and dragging the packages worked!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Pls take a look at if the classes already were created into /bin folder. And make sure you have set the correct JDK in library.

Comment: Oh yeah! That might be it.  I will clean the bin.